# how to clone a repo to a virtualenv on mac Mountain Lion

Tags: python, github, virtualenv, github-for-mac

I could be missing something fundamental here, but I'm struggling to work out what.

I'm using Github for Mac for the first time. I've found a repo i want to look at, so I've logged into GH and installed and configured the mac app.

I've created a virtualenv that I want to work in. added python 2.7.

I've forked the repo on GH. Then I've hit the clone to mac button. this works fine and asks me where i want to put it. the problem is here, the only action is to overwrite the whole directory. which isnt good.

ive checked the help for virtualenv and theres no convert to virtualenv option, which would allow me to download the project then make it a virtualenv.
im aware that i can probably get by with a copy and paste operation and two different folders, but this seems silly. Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal. `cd` into your virtualenv directory, and run `git clone` from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the answer by Osh to remind people that they need to activate the virtualenv before running git clone. So the action that worked for me assuming you have already installed virtualenv:

```
cd Virtualenvs/ 
virtualenv -p python2 repo_env
source repo_env/bin/activate
cd repo_env
git clone new_repo_address
```